# Finding part of string in list of strings

Tags: python

```
GCM = ([519,520,521,522,533],[534,525],[526,527,530,531], [4404])

slice = int(str(df["CGM"][row_count])[:3])
```

I am looking through a row in a csv file and taking out the number I want. i want the number that starts with the number I have in `GCM`. since they represent info I want in other columns. this has working fine with the slice function because all the number i wanted started with 3 digits. now that i need to look for any number that starts with `4404` and later on going to probably need to look for `57052` the slice function no longer work.

is there a way I can, instead of slicing and comparing to list, can take 5 digit number and see if part of it is in list. preferably look for it starting 3 or more same digits. the real point of that part of code is finding out which list in `GCM` list the number is. it need to be able to have the number `44042` and know that the part of it a care about is in `GCM[3]`, but on the other side do not want it to say that `32519` is in `DCM[0]` since I only care about number that start with `519` not ends with it.

[image]

ps. I am norwegian and have been learning programming by myself. been some long nights. so something here can be lost in translation.

Comment: Can you put a simple example also to tell what is it that you want? Am I correct in understanding that you want to filter out elements from a list which start from a particular number?

Comment: Can you give us input and output example?

Comment: GCM is a tuple containing lists of numbers, not strings.

Comment: You can use the `startswith()` method to tell if a string starts with another string.

Comment: Thank you. Think it was startswith() combined with any() needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.startswith()` to test if a substring is the beginning of another string, then you don't need to slice a particular length.

And you can use `any()` to test if any of the strings in a `GCM` list matches this way.

```
GCM = (['519','520','521','522','533'],['534','525'],['526','527','530','531'], ['4404'])
num = '44042'
for i, l in enumerate(GCM):
    if any(num.startswith(code) for code in l)
        print(f'Found {num} in GCM[{i}]')
        break
else:
    print(f'{num} not found in GCM')
```

Comment: If number are int, you can use `num.startswith(str(code))`

Comment: @DaniloToro True, but I don't like repeatedly converting to `str` in a loop. So that should be done once before the loops.

Comment: That is perfect! had tried any() and was working on a way to loop through all parts of GCM and comparing it to input from file. But it started to become really long and did not work. So this is something I will try as soon as I am home from work.